# Does $\int_{[1,z]}\frac{1}{u}du=\log(z)$ where $z\in\mathbb C$?

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

Does $$\int_{[1,z]}\frac{1}{u}du=\log(z)$$ where $z\in\mathbb C$ ? I know that on a closed circle that contain $0$ we have $$\int_C\frac{1}{z}dz=2i\pi=\log(1),$$

but for $$\int_{[1,z]}\frac{1}{u}du=\log(z)$$ I don't really know to compute the integral.

Comment: What do you mean by $\int_1^z$? You need to specify a path.

Comment: Are you treating $\log(z)$ as a (single-valued) *function*? If so, what definition are you using?

Comment: I suppose it is on the segment $[1,z]$

Comment: It is true that $e^{\int_1^z du/u}=z$ for any path from $1$ to $z$ not passing through $0$, but the exact result of the integral itself depends on the path. Different paths result in different logarithms.

Comment: @Joe, that segment would pass through $0$ if $z$ is a negative real number.

Comment: I corrected for $\int_1^z$. My definition is $\log(z)= \log(|z|)+i\arg(z).$ Is it a good definition ?

Comment: @user386627, if that's your definition of $\log(z)$, then how do you justify $2\pi i=\log(1)$?

Comment: With lowercase $\arg$, that definition is correct, but you should be sure to understand that e.g. $\arg(1)=\{ \dots,-4\pi i,-2 \pi i,0,2 \pi i,4 \pi i,\dots \}$ and in general $\arg(z)=\mathrm{Arg}(z) + 2 \pi i \mathbb{Z}$. Any particular path of integration selects a particular logarithm, so strictly speaking $\int_1^z du/u \in (\log(|z|) + i \arg(z))$, rather than $=$.

Comment: How do you define $\operatorname{arg}(z)$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos : As every one : If $z=re^{i\theta }$ then $arg(z)=\theta $,

Comment: @user386627 That doesn't define it, since there's more than one choice.

Comment: It's strange that : so many view, and no "acceptable" answer... is this my question totally stupid or come from no where ? $[1,z]$ is just the line from 1 to $z$ (and thus no loop...) and $arg(z)$ is the angle, and of course in $[0, 2\pi)$ or $[-\pi,\pi)$ or $(-\pi,\pi)$... if you want to exclude $\mathbb R^-$... Anyway, in general, with your definition (don't care about mine), what is $\int_{[1,z]}\frac{1}{u}du$ ? @JoséCarlosSantos and other people

Comment: @user386627 Your question is a natural one. You should just have stated  that your $\log$ is the main branch of the logarithm. I will be busy now but, unless someone provides an answer meanwhile, I wll answer your question as soon as possible.

Comment: @user386627, in the meantime, you might do well to look at the wikipedia article on the complex logarithm, in particular the section https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Constructing_branches_via_integration

Comment: When $[1,z]$ is just the segment, and $z$ is not a nonpositive real, you have the principal logarithm, denoted $\mathrm{Log}$ instead of $\log$. Thus e.g. $\int_{[1,i]} du/u=\pi i/2$.

Comment: @user386627 Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\log(z)$ is the main branch of the logarithm, then, yes, it is true. Of course, I am assuming that $[1,z]$ is that path $t\mapsto 1+t(z-1)$ ($[t\in[0,1]$).

Let $L(z)=\int_{[1,z]}\frac1u\,\mathrm du$. Then $L$ is differentiable and $L'(z)=\frac1z$. This is so because, by Morera's theorem,$$L(z+h)-L(z)=\int_{[1,z+h]}\frac1u\,\mathrm du-\int_{[1,z]}\frac1u\,\mathrm du=\int_{z,z+h}\frac1u\,\mathrm du$$and therefore\begin{align}\lim_{h\to0}\frac{L(z+h)-L(z)-\frac hz}h&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\int_{[z,z+h]}\frac1u\,\mathrm du-\frac hz}h\\&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\int_{z,z+h}\frac1u-\frac1z\,\mathrm dz}h.\end{align}Now, take $\varepsilon>0$. Fix a $\delta>0$ such that $|w-z|<\delta\implies\left|\frac1w-\frac1z\right|<\varepsilon$. Then, if $|h|<\delta$,$$\left|\frac{\int_{z,z+h}\frac1u-\frac1z\,\mathrm dz}h\right|\leqslant\frac{|h|\varepsilon}{|h|}=\varepsilon.$$So, this proves that$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{L(z+h)-L(z)-\frac hz}h=0,$$which means that $L'(z)=\frac1z$.

Now, I will prove that, for each $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0]$, $L(z)$ is a logarithm of $z$. Let $g(z)=\frac{e^{L(z)}}z$, Then$$g'(z)=\frac{z\frac1ze^{L(z)}-e^{L(z)}}{z^2}=0.$$So, $g$ is constant. Since $g(1)=\frac{e^0}1=1$, $g=1$ and therefore $e^{L(z)}=z$. In other words, $L(z)$ is a logarithm of $z$.

It remains to be proved that $L(z)=\log(z)$. Let $h(z)=L(z)-\log(z)$. Then$$(\forall z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0]):h(z)\in2\pi i z,$$since, for each $z$, $h(z)$ is the difference between two logarithms of $z$. But $h$ is continuous and its domain is connected. Since the only connected and non-empty subsets of $2\pi i\mathbb Z$ are those with a single element and since $h(1)=0$, then $h\left(\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0]\right)=\{0\}$. In other words, $h$ is the null function. So, $L=\log$.

Comment: can't have a better answer. thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Your equation, as written, is meaningless. The integral
$$
\int_{[1,z]}\frac{1}{u}\mathrm du
$$
has no unique value: it depends on how many times the path $\gamma(0)=1,\gamma(1)=z$ winds around the origin. On the other hand, the logarithm
$$
\log(z)
$$
has no unique value: the equation $\mathrm e^w=z$ has an infinite number of solutions, $w\in\log|z|+i (\arg z)\pi\mathbb Z$, with (say) $-\pi<\arg z\le \pi$.

*If* we agree to regard the integral as a symbolic notation for all the possible values it takes as $\gamma$ ranges over $\pi_1(\mathbb C\setminus\{0\})\cong\mathbb Z$, and the logarithm as the set of all solutions of $\mathrm e^w=z$, then both sides are identical, as sets (i.e., they contain the same elements).

Answer (score 1):

If $z$ is not a nonpositive real (i.e. $z$ is not real, or $z$ is real and $z>0$), and $[1,z]$ is the segment from $1$ to $z$, then $\int_{[1,z]} \frac{du}{u}=\mathrm{Log}(z)$, the principal logarithm. This is defined by the property that it agrees with the real logarithm on the positive real axis. Equivalently, it is defined by the branch cut through the negative real axis and the convention $\arg(z) \in (-\pi,\pi)$.